# ValueError in time-date data

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I'm facing issue in matching the format of time date data
time data '03-MAY-22 02.42.33.000000000 AM' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'
what should be the correct format for this date-time data?

For this time-date data '03-MAY-22 02.42.33.000000000 AM'
I've written this format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p' but this is not matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library doesn't support a resolution for the fraction-of-second finer than microseconds. You can remove the last three digits from the fraction-of-second and then parse the obtained string in the usual way.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

str_dt = '03-MAY-22 02.42.33.000000000 AM'
str_dt = re.sub(r'(\.\d{6})(\d{3})', r'\1', str_dt)
print(str_dt)

dt = datetime.strptime('03-MAY-22 02.42.33.000000 AM', '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')
print(dt)
```

**Output**:

```
03-MAY-22 02.42.33.000000 AM
2022-05-03 02:42:33
```

Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1v23Jh/1) to understand the regex pattern used in the solution. This solution replaces the regex match with group 1 of the match.